# installing ubuntu alongside win7(multi partition), cant get windows to boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I decided to give Linux a try, but I'm doing something wrong during the installation.

First I reinstalled Windows 7, did all of the updates, installed new browser and what not, then I created an image of the partition and went on to try to get Ubuntu installed alongside it.

First try, Ubuntu installed no problem, it would even boot but I messed something up because Windows would not boot any more, something about missing files/settings (I probably should have made better note of what it said exactly). There were 2 options to start Windows on the boot screen, the first option just returned me to the boot screen and the second gave the "Windows is missing something" screen.

No biggie, I reverted back with the system image, read up on some installation guides and tried again. Linux installed correctly and could boot up but again Windows didn't boot. This time on the boot screen if I selected Windows it just went back to the same boot screen.

I actually took some screenshots with my phone the second time:

[image: screenshot]

Anyway, here's what I am trying to get working; I have two internal hard drives, a normal one for files/games and such, and a SSD, partitioned like this:

- Windows partition 125GB,
- Linux partition 50GB,
- Linux swap 15GB
- remainder in a 4th partition for programs/games and such

2nd HDD,

- 39MB OEM partition (whatever that does, doesn't bother me so I just leave it) - 100gb partition for files, and rest in a 3rd partition for whatever else

So here's what I did with installing Linux the 2nd time:

- Selected the Windows partition, selected use as NTFS and mount point /windows
- created a 50GB partition for Linux, Ext4 file system and mount point /
- created a 15gb partition for swap drive
- then in the "device for boot loader installation" drop down menu I selected the Windows partition

Linux boots no problem but when I select to start windows in the boot menu it just goes right back to the boot menu. Clearly I am doing something wrong, probably forgetting something but I cant figure out what.

I hope someone here can point out my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, after talking with some other people, it turned out I selected the wrong place for the "device for boot loader installation"
I first selected the windows partition(red arrow in bottom image) where I should just have chosen the drive itself(black arrow)

Both linux and windows boot now, so I'm off to explore the wonderful world of Linux :)

Maybe this will be useful for someone else in the future